# Array index [""0""] after JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I'm trying to parse data like this:

```
{
"streets": [{
    "street": "*Gewerbegebiet1",
    "hnr_needed": true
  }, {
    "street": "Abzweig Kienbaum",
    "hnr_needed": true
  }, {
    "street": "Ahornallee (Eggersdorf)",
    "hnr_needed": true
  }, {
    "street": "Ahornallee (Rehfelde)",
    "hnr_needed": true
  }, {
    "street": "Ahornweg",
    "hnr_needed": true
  }, {
    "street": "Akazienstr. (Altlandsberg)",
    "hnr_needed": true
  }, {
    "street": "Akazienstr. (Eggersdorf)",
    "hnr_needed": true
  }, {
    "street": "Akazienweg",
    "hnr_needed": true
  }, {
    "street": "Alte Dorfstr.",
    "hnr_needed": true
  }, {
    "street": "Alte Heerstr.",
    "hnr_needed": true
  }, {
    "street": "Alte Muehle",
    "hnr_needed": true
  }, ...
```

with this code (data is the JSON-Array):

```
data = JSON.parse(data);
data = data.streets;
for (var i = 0; i <= data.length; i++) {
  street_autocomplete.push( data[i].street );
}
$('#street').prop('disabled', false);
```

However, the first index of the array is not [0] but [""0""]. With every other index ([1], etc) it works fine.
Could you give me a pointer please?

Comment: Please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52849136/edit), then click the `[<>]` snippet editor and produce a [mcve] - it is not at all clear what you mean by `[""0""]`

Comment: In order to see what's going on, debug your raw data.

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the [shortest program necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to reproduce the problem before posting._

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you have a single index problem by iterating over the last index.

```
for (var i = 0; i <= data.length; i++) {
//                 ^
```

should be

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
//                ^
```

Comment: I will accept the answer in 8 minutes, the question is not old enough yet.

Comment: Or better. Delete the question since it is a `typo-type` question